# Array type with range assignment needed

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy, python-3.x

In NumPy, whole segments of arrays can be assigned using `:` as a wildcard for index ranges. For example:

```
>>> (n, m) = (5,5)
>>> a = numpy.array([[0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)])
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

>>> for i in range(n):
...     a[i, :] = [1 for j in range(m)]
>>> a
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

However, `numpy.array` only holds numeric data. I need an array type which can hold arbitrary objects and can be addressed like NumPy arrays. What should I use?

EDIT: I'd like the full flexibility of this range assignment syntax, e.g. this should work, too:

```
>>> a[:,1] = 42
>>> a
array([[ 1, 42,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1, 42,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1, 42,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1, 42,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1, 42,  1,  1,  1]])
```

Comment: Do you only need that specific case, or are simple cases like this sufficent? In that case, the builtin list works just fine, you just omit the comma.

Comment: @delnan Neither. I'd like to use this syntax for more complex cases, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something here but numpy does in fact hold objects as well as numbers.

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: complex = {'field' : 'attribute'}

In [3]: class ReallyComplex(dict):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [4]: a = numpy.array([complex,ReallyComplex(),0,'this is a string'])

In [5]: a
Out[5]: array([{'field': 'attribute'}, {}, 0, this is a string], dtype=object)
In [6]: subsection = a[2:]

In [7]: subsection
Out[7]: array([0, this is a string], dtype=object)
```

When you place complex objects into a numpy array the `dtype` becomes `object`.  You can access members and slices of the array as you would with normal numpy arrays.  I'm not familiar with the serialization but you may experience drawbacks in that area.

If you are convinced that numpys are not the way to go a standard Python list is a great way to maintain a collection of objects and you may also slice the python list the very similar to the numpy array.

```
 std_list = ['this is a string', 0, {'field' : 'attribute'}]
 std_list[2:]
```

Comment: "numpy does in fact hold objects as well as numbers."

I was not aware of that, because I tried: 
>>> a[0,0] = None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

I guess that solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If numpy doesn't do what you need, standard Python lists will:

```
>>> (n, m) = (5,5)
>>> 
>>> class Something:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return("Something()")
... 
>>> class SomethingElse:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return("SomethingElse()")
... 
>>> a = [[Something() for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
>>> 
>>> for i in range(n):
...     a[i] = [SomethingElse() for j in range(m)] #Use a[i][:] if you want to modify the sublist, not replace it.
... 
>>> a
[[SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse()],
[SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse()],
[SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse()],
[SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse()],
[SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse(), SomethingElse()]]
```